# How to return a WebElement in this scenario

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I wanted to utilize page objects and following is what i am looking at:

I have created a package 'pageObjects' and created a class 'HomePage' with element like below:

```
public class HomePage 
{
    private static WebElement element=null;

    public static WebElement txt_UserName(WebDriver driver)
    {
        element=driver.findElement(By.name("userName"));
        return element;
    }
}
```

Here in my Test Case, when i use `HomePage.txt_UserName(driver).sendKeys("uday")` 
lets enter the username as "Uday". This works perfect.

But what i need to implement above in a method like
enterValue("HomePage.txt_UserName","Uday")

```
public void enterValue(String strObjID,String strValue)
{
  //How should i use the above parameter here?? Something like below should work
  strObjID(driver).sendKeys(strValue);

}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Please, add more details to improve your question. BTW, `strObjID(driver)` does not compile in Java.

Comment: it will not compile for sure, that i know. but wanted something like that so that represents a WebElement. I am planning to use the above approach for cucumber, where i enter a step in feature file like   "Then enter a value "udayanem" in "HomePage.txt_UserName"" which converted to stepDefinitions like @Then("^enter a value \"([^\"]*)\" in \"([^\"]*)\"$")
 public void enterValueInAField(String strValue, WebElement strPageObjName) throws Throwable 
 {
  strPageObjName(driver).sendKeys(strValue);
 }. Please let me know if it not clear.

Comment: Why do you pass a String? You could pass a WebElement insted of the strObjID and perform a sendKeys to the passed WebElement. Still I don't know why someone should do something like this...i would just rather stay with sendKeys instead of making a new method like enterValue

Comment: Inspite of String,i also tried with WebElement, the above code(comments section) contains WebElement itself.

Comment: Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment I think you should not write a generic cucumber step definition which handle all types of input fields. This makes it very hard to read and understand your feature files. Writing HTML ID or CSS selector into your HTML does not fulfil BDD because you write requirements at first and because of this you can not know which IDs you are using. Look at the [principles of BDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development#Principles_of_BDD).

Remember, that the purpose of a feature file is to link a requirement, written as user story, to your test code. So write your feature files like your user stories. For example:

```
Given I loaded the home page
When I enter my username <username>
And I enter my password <password>
And I press the login in button
Then I should be redirected to <some url>
```

Based on that, you should implement the [page object pattern](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) thoroughly. Here is an example:

```
public class HomePage {
    private final WebElement usernameElement;
    // declare more page elements here

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        usernameElement = driver.findElement(By.name("userName"));
        // init more page elements here
    }

    public void enterUsername(String username) {
        usernameElement.sendKeys(username)
    }

    // more handler here: e.g. public void enterPassword(String password) ...
}
```

In your cucumber step definition you can then use the page object:

```
@Then("^I enter my username \"(.+)\"$")
public void I_enter_my_username(String username) {
    homepage.enterUsername(username);
}
```

This pattern allows a good understanding of your feature files and how they are connected to your test code.

Comment: i want enter value as more generic function, for which i want to object and value. The above code works for sample practice coding, but when we think at framework level, better have a separate method for these key functions the way i am looking at.

Comment: This makes your feature file useless because you need to write the ids oder CSS selectors in your feature files. When you do this, you are mixing the written requirement with the technical implementation. This is not appropriate to BDD first where you write your requirement first, therefore you can not know which IDs you are using. I'm trying you to convince not to do this. It is not BDD anymore!

Comment: I agree your point, but the thing is if we have 50-100 objects in a page/form i dont want to write 50 different step definition functions for setting a value. In a similar way if we have 50-100 operations, we need not to have 50-100 click methods in step definitions.

Comment: OK, I'm wondering which user wants to interact with 50-100 elements in a form?

Comment: If your form has 50 elements, you have to address them somewhere. Schrieveslaach is pointing out, and I agree with him, that this should be done inside the page object.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't make a generic function. If your form has 50 elements, you will have to deal with all 50 at some point anyway. The better practice is to put all the code in the page object rather than the test case script. You should not require a consumer (script writer) to have knowledge of the HTML of the page. They should be able to call a simple function like `login(username, password)`... not `enterValue("some crazy XPath", "my name")` and `enterValue("some other crazy XPath", "my password")`. People that come along later are not going to be able to tell what each line does which will make debugging much harder and more time consuming.

I agree with Schrieveslaach but I would take a slightly different approach. I would say that you should bundle the elements into actions that a user would perform on the page. For example, instead of `enterUsername()` and `enterPassword()` and `clickLogin()`, use `login(username, password)` that fills in the username and password and clicks the login button. That will simplify the API of your page object and only expose necessary actions. Who is going to fill in a username but not a password? There will be times where you will want to fill in some fields but not others, maybe for negative testing, in those cases you can pass in empty string for some fields and accomplish this.

Comment: I agree with you JeffC, i dont wanted the client to restrict anything, so common operations/actions i will provide the same way, like login, navigateTo("so and so page") etc..., here as code behind we can handle page objects, But if the client may want a single statement in couple of places where then want enter some value or click some link i wanted them these generic functions.

Comment: @JeffC, I think we are on the same page. :-) And I agree, `login(username, password)` is much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't deal with WebElements or XPaths outside PageObjects. The purpose of a pageobject is to encapsulate all the page identifier complexity and return user friendly outputs. You should be able to call a simple action like login("username", "password") without ever dealing with Xpaths, CSS selectors outside.

If you're looking to wrap some of Selenium's more complex functions (getDriver, etc), use an AbstractPageObject to provide more generic functions which all the PageObjects inherit from, or make static functions in a common class.

If you are interacting with a large number of identifiers on your pageObject, and this is undesirable, you have a few different ways of dealing with this:

**1) Split your page object up into smaller page objects**

Page objects do not have to represent a single webpage, so much as a collection of related elements on a page. Your menu could be a single pageobject, or a table. If you wish to represent the hierarchy you can include it as an public object on the parent page, e.g.:

```
public class HomepageObject {

    public MenuPageObject menuPageObject;

    private By element1 = By.id("element-1");
    private By element2 = By.id("element-2");

    public void clickElement1() {
        click(element1);
    }

    ...

}
```

That way you can access the menu by using e.g.:

```
 homepage.menuPageObject.clickStuff()
```

The other advantage this has if you have repeated elements on lots of pages, you don't have to keep on including them!

**2) Make your identifiers more generic**

Alternatively, your elements may be similar, and you can refer to them by a single identifier. The following snippet of code deals with a potentially large list of stuff which share similar IDs. I've used Java 8 streams in this example, but you can just use a foreach loop if you find it easier.

```
    private By displayedStuff = By.cssSelector("p[id^='stuff-number-']");

    public Optional<String> getStuff(String stuffText){

         // get a list of the elements
         List<WebElement> stuffList = getDriver().findElements(displayedStuff)

         // return the element text which matches stuffText
         return stuffList.stream()
              .map(e -> e.getText())
              .filter(e -> e.contains(stuffText))
              .findFirst();
    }
```

Your stufflist could be anything: buttons, tables, dropdowns.. there is probably a lot of repetition on your page if you've got that number of elements. Unless your developers are handcoding 100 unique elements too?

**3) Consider cutting down the number of elements you have on a page.**

If you don't want to deal with 100 different elements, consider how your users might feel!